# quickest barplot of data.table aggregation

Tags: r, plot, data.table, bar-chart

I have some data, which I aggregate using `data.table`. Suppose, this is the aggregated data.

```
library(data.table); set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(id=1:10, val=round(runif(10,100,200)))

> dat
    id val
 1:  1 191
 2:  2 194
 3:  3 129
 4:  4 183
 5:  5 164
 6:  6 152
 7:  7 174
 8:  8 113
 9:  9 166
10: 10 171
```

I wonder what might be the quickest way to get a bar chart of this. `barplot(dat)` produces the error that `'height' must be a vector or matrix` so my workaround is

```
vals <- dat$val
names(vals) <- dat$id
barplot(vals)
```

but I suspect that there is a faster way as this is quite cumbersome for a quick check. Of course, in many cases I do not need to aggregate at all and can use `hist(.)` on the raw data. However, I often find it easier to aggregate in `data.table` when aggregations are somewhat more complicated.

Comment: You can do this in `j`: `dat[, barplot(val, names = id)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula interface to `barplot`:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(id = 1:10, val = round(runif(10, 100, 200)))

barplot(val ~ id, dat)
```

[image: result]

Alternatively, `barplot(dat$val, names.arg = dat$id)` works as well.